# Debugging in Android Studio doesn't work because INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT

Tags: android-studio

After connecting a real device and debugging the virtual device stopped working.

So I deleted the virtual device and create a new one.

But now when I click either `Run` or `Debug` it comes up with this warning

[image]

so I click "OK" and then nothing happens but this appears:

```
06/05 11:18:19: Launching 'app' on Nexus 7 API 22.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT
The device might have stale dexed jars that don't match the current version (dexopt error).
Retry
```

Can I ever debug on a virtual device ever again? How?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue of reading the latest emulator state or something similar.

I've been able to fix that by wiping data from a selected emulator and cold booting it.

1. Open AVD Manager by clicking on it's icon:

[image: AVD Manager icon]

or by double-clicking `Shift` key, typing in `AVD Manager` and clicking on desired option:

[image: Searching for AVD Manager tool by searching "All" category]

2. From a list of emulators you have find the one that is causing you trouble. On the end right side find arrow pointing down. Click on it and select `Wipe Data`:

[image: Selecting Wipe Data option in AVD Manager menu]

3. Click the same arrow and click `Cold Boot Now`.

From now on your emulator should work fine.